# What does this iptables rule mean: tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU?

Tags: linux, networking, router, dd-wrt, iptables

What does this iptables rule mean: `tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU`?

Doing `iptables -vnL` on my DD-WRT router shows the following rule in the `FORWARD` chain: `TCPMSS tcp -- * * 0.0.0.0/0 0.0.0.0/0 tcp flags:0x06/0x02 TCPMSS clamp to PMTU`.

Instead of the common actions of `ACCEPT` or `DROP` it is `TCPMSS`. What does this mean?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's a pretty standard `iptables` rule to prevent PMTU discovery issues.

From [this](http://lartc.org/howto/lartc.cookbook.mtu-mss.html):

> ... Path MTU Discovery doesn't work as well as it should anymore. If you know for a fact that a hop somewhere in your
>   network has a limited (<1500) MTU, you cannot rely on PMTU Discovery
>   finding this out.
>
> Besides MTU, there is yet another way to set the maximum packet size,
>   the so called Maximum Segment Size. This is a field in the TCP Options
>   part of a SYN packet.
>
> Recent Linux kernels, and a few PPPoE drivers (notably, the excellent
>   Roaring Penguin one), feature the possibility to 'clamp the MSS'.
>
> The good thing about this is that by setting the MSS value, you are
>   telling the remote side unequivocally 'do not ever try to send me
>   packets bigger than this value'. No ICMP traffic is needed to get this
>   to work.
>
> The bad thing is that it's an obvious hack - it breaks 'end to end' by
>   modifying packets. Having said that, we use this trick in many places
>   and it works like a charm.
>
> In order for this to work you need at least iptables-1.2.1a and Linux
>   2.4.3 or higher. The basic command line is:
>
> `# iptables -A FORWARD -p tcp --tcp-flags SYN,RST SYN -j TCPMSS  --clamp-mss-to-pmtu`